# TextBoxColumn in DevexpressGridControl (WPF)

Tags: wpf, grid, devexpress

In Windows grid is sucha a thing like 
`DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();`

Is something like that in DevExpress GridControll for WPF?Or maybe is possible to do some workaround?

Comment: Or maybe its possible to use the same DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and put it into WPF grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column like this DevExpress.Wpf.Grid.GridColumn col = new GridColumn(); in WPF can do everything the same as DataGridViewTextBoxColumn in WinForms. Only the property names can be a little different.